# Bar Button Image is white

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Image in bar button show image white  http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/1846/6l5n.png but image is not white.How i do fix this?

This image http://imageshack.us/a/img13/5332/k3jb.png

Comment: That is standard behavior with iOS toolbars and navbars. The images you use are only alpha masks for generating the final icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIBarButtonItem` has a `tintColor` property that you can set (since iOS 5). UIKit only use the image you specify as a mask with this tintColor, whose default is white on iOS 5 and 6